# Read Date from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How do I read a date from SQL Server to a `datetime` variable in C# ?

```
DateTime sDate = (read["notDate"]);
```

I get error

> Cannot convert object to a system.datetime [are you missing a cast?]

Edit: the SQL Server uses a `Date` datatype for this column.

Then how will format the `sDate` to UK format - I was looking at

```
format("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Using ASP.NET, C#, SQL Server Express.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try an explicit cast as the message tells you?

Comment: Did you try using a cast as the error suggested? `DateTime sDate = (DateTime)read["notDate"];` The format has nothing to do with anything at this point. The format is only for display purposes (or parsing).

Comment: @itsme86 - thank you!

Comment: What the heck is `read`?

Comment: he must of called SqlDataReader variable name read @ErikPhilips i.e. SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to cast it into a date.. this should do the job

```
DateTime sDate = (DateTime)read["notDate"];
```

To then format it into a `dd/MM/yyyy` you can do

```
string formattedDate = sDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: if it has solved it please mark it as accepted (the green tick) so others can find the answer quicker. @Azmodan

Comment: lol sorry been a long day! @juharr corrected my terms. You see i called my parameter formattedDate ;)